# Cannot get function to acknowledge objects returned in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, scope

I am trying to create a game like Text Twist (https://texttwist2.co/) and have gotten the initial layout of the game set up. I have 6 empty divs that are each populated with button on which one of the letters is displayed:

```js
let startButton = document.getElementById("start");
let letterButtonArray = [];
startButton.addEventListener("click", function startRound() {

  let wordLettersShuffled = ['A', 'R', 'D', 'A', 'O', 'B']

  let letterBalls = document.getElementsByClassName("letter-ball");
  for (let i = 0; i < letterBalls.length; i++) {
    let letterButton = document.createElement("button");
    letterButton.innerHTML = wordLettersShuffled[i];
    letterButton.setAttribute("class", "letter-button");
    letterButton.addEventListener("click", moveLetter);
    letterBalls[i].appendChild(letterButton);
    letterButtonArray.push(letterButton);
  }
  return letterButtonArray
}, {
  once: true
})

console.log(letterButtonArray) // 

function moveLetter() {
  alert(letterButton.innerHTML)
}
```

```html
<div id="ball-container">
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
  <div class="letter-ball"></div>
</div>

<button id="start">START GAME</button>
```

When I click one of the letterButtons I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: letterButton is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.moveLetter".

When I passed the letterButton as a parameter in the function, as:

```
function moveLetter(letterButton) {
    alert(letterButton.innerHTML)
}
```

an alert comes up but says "undefined".

I'm ultimately trying to move the individual letterButton to another div when clicked, but I can't get the moveLetter function to recognize the letterButtons that make up the letterButtonArray. Can anyone help? Thanks!

P.S. I console logged the letterButtonArray ahead of the moveLetter function to ensure that the array is returning the correct objects. It shows as below with the innerHTML noted:

```
0: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "A"
1: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "R"
2: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "D"
3: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "A"
4: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "O"
5: button.letter-button  --> innerHTML: "B"
length: 6
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: The argument passed to an event listener is an `Event` object, not the target of the event. You need `letterButton.target.innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, no identifier of the name `letterButton` is found in the scope of `moveLetter()`.

The scope (and the identifiers therein) that `moveLetter` is aware of is defined at function creation, which in this case means the global scope only. Therefore it is not aware of the for-loop's scope and its identifiers (`letterButton`).

Here are some nudges towards how you can solve your issue. If short on time, I recommend reading section "Using the event object".

## Using closures

As mentioned before, a functions "knowledge" about identifiers is determined at function creation, even if the function is returned to a scope outside its initial scope. This is called a "closure".

**Sidenote:** [Function statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) are hoisted to the nearest context (function/global scope), but [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) and [arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) are scoped to the nearest scope (block/function/global scope).

We can make use of closures so that the `moveLetter` will know what identifier we mean with `letterButton`. Example:

```js
for (const button of document.getElementsByTagName("button")) { // Block scope
  const clickHandler = function() {
    // Uses identifier `button` of the for-loop's block scope.
    // Therefore, it closes around that (the narrowest) scope.
    console.log(button.textContent);
  };
  
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me too!</button>
```

**Sidenote:** For-loops create a new scope for each iteration (when using `let`/`const`). That is why the similarly named identifier `button` references different objects for each iteration.

As you can see, the function is aware of the identifiers if it is in the same scope as them.

Creating the function anywhere inside the scope works, even inline in the `addEventListener()` call. Therefore, you may often see something similar to this:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // This function is created inline (anonymously).
  // It shares the same scope with identifier `button`, and is therefore aware of it.
  console.log(button.textContent);
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

## Binding the arguments

We can bind certain arguments to a function (e.g. with [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). That way, no closure is created, and we can use the parameters of our function.

```js
for (const button of document.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler.bind(null, button));
}

function clickHandler(button) {
  console.log(button.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me too!</button>
```

Similarly, you may see something like this:

```js
for (const button of document.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => clickHandler(button));
}

function clickHandler(button) {
  console.log(button.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me too!</button>
```

Here, the arrow function creates a closure around `button`, but passes it as an argument to `clickHandler()`. Therefore, we effectively "bind" the argument to `clickHandler()`. Personally I find that this is just an **unclean way of binding** arguments.

## Using the event object

Since `moveLetter` is added via [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), it is passed the current [event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) as its first argument.

Using [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), we can find the clicked button.

**Sidenote:** If a descendant of the listening element is clicked, `event.target` will reference the clicked descendant. We can use [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the relevant (ancestral?) element.

```js
for (const button of document.getElementsByTagName("button")) {
  button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(evt) {
  // Using `closest()` is unnecessary here, because our buttons don't have any children.
  // We can still use it though.
  const button = evt.target.closest("button");
  console.log(button.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me too!</button>
```

Using the event object allows us to use even another method, which I'd prefer:

### Using event delegation

Event delegation describes the use of one event listener of a common ancestor to provide functionality to multiple elements. As we learned, we can find the relevant element using `event.target` and optionally with `Element.closest()`.

The above example may therefore look like this:

```js
const commonAncestor = document.body;
commonAncestor.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler(evt) {
  const button = evt.target.closest("button");
  if (button === null) {
    // No button was clicked
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(button.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<button>Click me too!</button>
```

The *advantage* of this is that it uses less listeners and therefore less memory, scales easier (new elements will come with "attached" listeners), and you don't have to worry about potentially destroying your listeners (e.g. by assigning to `innerHTML` of your element).

The *disadvantage* of this is that it may be complicated to understand, and that the listener is declared elsewhere than where the elements are created.

Generally, I suggest to use event delegation to reduce duplicate code and have the browser perform optimizations as to which elements should react to given events.

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar commented earlier, *"The argument passed to an event listener is an Event object, not the target of the event."* When defining the event handler<sup>✪</sup> `moveLetter`, it is actually:

```
function moveLetter(event) {...`
```

...by default. The argument `event`<sup>⚝</sup> is an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)
object that has built-in properties and methods that help us facilitate the control over the DOM when the registered event is triggered as well as some control over the registered event itself. The following table describes a few identifiers and properties that could be useful in the context of the event handler `moveLetter(event)`:

| JavaScript | Description | Context |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `.currentTarget` | References the element that the event handler/listener is attached to | `letterButton` |
| `.target` | References the actual element that the user is interacting with. This reference could be different than `.currentTarget` if the event handler is designed to employ [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) in order to control multiple elements triggered by the registered event | `letterButton` |
| `this` | If within an event handler, it is `.currentTarget` | `letterButton` |

As you can see, there are a few ways to find the same object within an event handler but always be aware that `.target` is specific to whatever the user interacted with (ex. the element user clicked, entered text into, focused on/out, hovered over, etc.), which isn't always `this` or `.currentTarget` (but in this case it is because each individual button has it's own event handler).

In the example below, the event handler `moveLetter(event)` uses the event property `.currentTarget`. Commented source are alternatives. Also, the eventListener with the event handler `moveLetter(event)` has been commented out and in it's place is an eventListener with a new event handler called `moveButton(event)`. `moveButton` will actually move a clicked button over to either `div.word` (which I added to the example) or `div.ball`. If you prefer the original event handler, uncomment:

```
// letterButton.addEventListener("click", moveLetter);
```

and comment or remove:

```
letterButton.addEventListener("click", moveButton);
```

I also removed the `once` option and added:

```
this.disabled = true`
```

...because it's not the best strategy if you intend to play the game on a single round without any pause between time allotted per word (messy and confusing UX). Just disable the start button when it's clicked then enable it at the end of each round.

One more change is that the array formally called `wordLettersShuffled` is now just `letters` and it is defined outside of the eventListener so it'll be easier to change to a new word every round. As a general rule, `eventListeners`, and event properties, etc are isolated and limited in certain ways so that specific elements involved with user interaction can be easily located and controlled. Try defining variables that change dynamically outside of event handlers/listeners or store values within elements instead of within an event handler/listener.

If you prefer not to define variables as I suggested, there are other ways far more complex but well worth using if under certain circumstances or if you intend to expand in the future (see Oskar Grosser's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654058/2813224))

<sup>✪</sup> <sup>The function that is invoked when the registered event is triggered.</sup>

<sup>⚝</sup> <sup>By convention the event object is commonly labeled as `event`, `e`, or `evt`. Since it's variable, it can be named just as any standard variable, but it should be clear and concise as possible.</sup>

```js
const startButton = document.getElementById("start");
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
const word = document.querySelector('.word');

let letterButtonArray = [];
let letters = ['A', 'R', 'D', 'A', 'O', 'B'];

startButton.addEventListener("click", startRound);

function startRound(event) {
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    let letterButton = document.createElement("button");
    letterButton.innerHTML = letters[i];
    letterButton.classList.add("letter-button");
    // letterButton.addEventListener("click", moveLetter);
    letterButton.addEventListener("click", moveButton);
    ball.append(letterButton);
    letterButtonArray.push(letterButton);
  }
  this.disabled = true;
}

function moveLetter(event) {
  console.log(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  /* Alternative 1 *///  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
  /* Alternative 2 */// console.log(this.innerHTML);
}

function moveButton(event) {
  if (this.parentElement.matches('.ball')) {
    word.append(this);
  } else {
    ball.append(this);
  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  min-height: 4ex
}
```

```html
<div class="word box"></div>
<div class="ball box"></div>

<button id="start">START GAME</button>
```

Comment: Your table and some of the sentences prior do not apply to listeners added via the (**discouraged**) HTML `onevent` attributes. I fixed my answer once I realized. (+1 Great read)

Comment: I used to mention the `onevent` attribute (aka inline attribute) for the sake of completeness but always needed to back peddle and mention it shouldn't be used. Now I just post this: [inline event handlers are garbage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) when it's used in the OP. (+1 to yours as well, very thorough)

Comment: This is great- only issue is that it's adding all letterButtons to the same ball div. There's six separate divs for each ball and each word (which I've renamed "box" as completed words have their own container to populate). Is there any way to add a button to each individual div? I changed the ball and word variables to let ballArray = document.getElementsByClassName("letter-ball"); and let boxArray = document.getElementsByClassName("letter-box");. For the moveLetter function I replaced append(this) to $('.boxArray:empty:first').append(this) and $('.ballArray:empty:first').append(this)

Comment: The reason why I removed the `<div>`s that were wrapped around the `<button>`s and didn't add any `<div>`s to the `<div class='word'>` is because there'll be extra code that's not really needed. Also, be aware that `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a Live HTMLCollection which is an array-like object that updates instantly which makes it very difficult to track the individual elements if the HTMLCollection changes in length. `.querySelectorAll()` returns a "static" array-like object called a `NodeList` which makes it ideal for iteration (which you'll need to do).(cont...)

Comment: (...cont), Do you plan on using 6 letters every round or a range of letters (ex. 4 to 6 letters) every round? Going back on the extra `<div>`s, they are block level elements so those buttons are displayed vertically which makes reading the letters unnecessarily difficult (recall that [Twist2](https://texttwist2.co/) game displays buttons vertically). I don't understand the use of `$('.ballArray:empty:first')` and `$('.boxArray:empty:first')` -- what is the actual behavior you are trying to employ? In Twist2, clicked button is moved to the other `<div>` in the order it was clicked.